# how to open a program using -clean on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell, command

need to know the command of what to add to the properties of the program I want to execute using the -clean option

I know that on windows you just add -clean to the end of the target on the properties of the program shortcut, but don't have a linux machine to be able to try this out and need to write some documentation on how it's done on Linux

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What program are you trying to run?

Comment: an eclipse based product

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the Eclipse options are shared among all operating systems. I have used `-clean` with Eclipse on my Linux system several times and it worked as expected.

If you are asking "How to launch Eclipse (or an Eclipse-based product) with the `-clean` option on Linux?", then the answer would have to depend on how Eclipse is launched in the first place. For example:

- If it is launched through the shell command prompt, then prepending the `-clean` option should be enough:

  ```
  ./eclipse -clean ...
  ```
- If it is launched through a desktop icon or menu, then the user should modify the shortcut through whatever method is provided by their desktop environment.

  Unfortunately (or fortunately) there are several desktop environments available on Linux, each with its own differences. If you are writing documentation that may be read by novices, you will probably have to try the main DEs of the major distributions and document the process - or at least find suitable documentation links on the Web.